# AngularJS setting up a factory that iterates through a ng-repeat array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working my way through setting up a factory. With help from here I have moved several functions from my OrderFormController to a factory. I have ran into a new problem regarding a function that uses forEach to go through a dynamic ng-repeat array. here is what i have..

code of OrderFormController that holds the function i'm trying to move..

```
app.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = function(){

    var total = 0;
    var dtotal = 0;
    var ftotal = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.items.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            dtotal+= s.qty * s.price;
        }
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.options.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            ftotal+= s.price;
        }
    });
    total = dtotal + ftotal;

    return total;
    };
});
```

here is the factory

```
app.factory('OrderData', function() {
    var OrderFactory = {};

    OrderFactory.total = function(){

    var total = 0;

    angular.forEach(item, function(item){
        if (item.active){
            total+= item.qty * item.price;
        }
    });

    return total;
    };

return OrderFactory;

});
```

my new controller im trying to use

```
app.controller('OrderController', function($scope, OrderData) {

    $scope.total = OrderData.total;

});
```

html snippet

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true" 
              layout="row">
              <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
              <span flex></span>
              <span>{{ item.price | currency}}</span>
              <span ng-repeat="option in options.results | filter:true">{{ option.name }}</span>
</md-list-item>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list-item layout="row">
    <span>Order Total :</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ total() | currency}}</span>
</md-list-item>
```

thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1):

You total method should accept `item` parameter & from UI you should pass `items.results` object so that service can iterate that array.

**Code**

```
OrderFactory.total = function(items) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if (item.active) {
            total += item.qty * item.price;
        }
    });
    return total;
};
```

**Markup**

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true" layout="row">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ item.price | currency}}</span>
    <span ng-repeat="option in options.results | filter:true">{{ option.name }}</span>
</md-list-item>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list-item layout="row">
    <span>Order Total :</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ total(items.results) | currency}}</span>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: @ChrisG there was mistak of item & items..could you try updated answer

Comment: thanks i have answer below... the data was held in items.results

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was

```
<span>{{ total(items) | currency}}</span>
```

needed to be changed to

```
<span>{{ total(items.results) | currency}}</span>
```